# Regex Python not working correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hy, I have an issue with regex python 3.

**Here is my code :**

```
# Here is regex 1, have to find tk_common on file tmp/out-file.txt
regex1 = re.compile(r'tk_common')
with open("tmp/out-file.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
                    result = regex1.search(line)

# If found : 
if regex1.search is not None:
    print("I find tk_common in out-file")

# else :
else:
    print("I didn't find tk_common in out-file")


# And here is the second one 
regex2 = re.compile(r'tk_text')
with open("tmp/out-file.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
                    result = regex2.search(line)

if regex2.search is not None:
    print("I find tk_text in out-file")
else:
    print("I didn't fint tk_text in out-file")
```

**My issue :**

I have two print message success when i start my programm :

```
I find tk_common in out-file
I find tk_text in out-file
```

But in fact, **it should not :**

```
$ cat tmp/out-file.txt | grep "tk_common\|tk_text"
<div class="tk_common">
```

Any idea ?
Thanks,

Comment: regex1.search and regex2.search are functions (which are not `None`). You are looking for `result` which is the result. Besides your code will only check the last line, because go to everyline and after you checked each line you investigate the result.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if regex1.search is not None:
```

will never be `None` because `regex1.search` refers to the `search` method, not to the return value of that method. Therefore your code always thinks that there is a match.

I think that you meant to check the `result` variable, not `regex1.search`.

```
regex1 = re.compile(r'tk_common')
with open("tmp/out-file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = regex1.search(line)
        if result is not None:
            print("I find tk_common in out-file")
            break
    else:
        print("I didn't find tk_common in out-file")
```

It is unnecessary to compile the re pattern because it will be [cached by the re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) anyway. Also, since you don't use the match object saved in `result`, you could just test the result of `re.search()` directly:

```
with open("tmp/out-file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.search(r'tk_common', line) is not None:
            print("I find tk_common in out-file")
            break
    else:
        print("I didn't find tk_common in out-file")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if regex1.search is not None:
```

Should be `result`

```
if result is not None
```

Because `re.compile().search` is a function, and most definitely not `None`. You want to look at the return value.

Also, your loop

```
regex1 = re.compile(r'tk_common')
with open("tmp/out-file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
                result = regex1.search(line)
```

If you find it on line 1, but then not on line 2, your result is going to be None and give a false negative. You should do `if result: break`

Using the Regex engine is a little overkill to simple do "is this string a substring". You can just do something like this

```
found_tk = False
with open('filename', 'r') as file_handle:
    for line in file_handle:
        if 'tk_text' in line:
            found_tk = True
            break
```